# how to restore deleted songs on an iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, data-recovery

I have a collection of several GB of mp3 files that were erased the last time I charged my iPod on my computer. The Apple store representative claims that this sync happens automatically anytime iTunes is connected to a computer but I have been downloading songs onto my iPod from different computers and CDs for several years now and this has never happened. In short, most of my songs were deleted, and are greyed out on my iPod. It is devastating. I have tried to find a solution to restore the files but cannot find one that does not involve uploading from a backup (which stupidly I do not have.) I have come across software [like this Disk drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjw6ZLOBRALEiwAxzyCWy2ai2op530Xw5znF8cq5YpyqGf7Pxd63Qq3yDTdJed1XaUuL10fExoCJdYQAvD_BwE) which is quite expensive so I would like a second opinion first.

What is the best option to recover deleted files and which software is recommended to do this on a Mac? Any arcane, convoluted methods are appreciated.

Comment: One app I've used to access files otherwise inaccessible on iDevices is [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer). YMMV _Disclaimer_: Satisfied customer of Macroplant LLC; no financial or other ties.

Comment: If they were bought from the iTunes store you can re-download them. If these were songs you ripped yourself and did not save on your various computers then they are likely gone for good.